# How to retrieve a value from an array if it is already have been removed in C# or VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

Is it possible to retrieve a value from an array if it has been removed e.g.

I have an array of values [1,100,44,55,1223,5653,....] 
now if a certain value is removed it will replace by 0 hence if 100 is removed then the updated array would be [1,0,44,55,1223,5653,....].
Now in this case, is it possible that we can retrieve 100?? Also there isn't any state management is used to store the value.

This question was asked to me in an interview and I told them that if we cannot use any kind of state management such as session, cookie etc, then we cannot retrieve it. I just wanted to clarify whether it is possible or not. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "removed" ? If you overwrite an array value, you  don't have a straight forward way to retrive it.

Comment: No, if you don't save value from array anywhere before remove it you cannot restore it

Comment: values are stored in memory. not in disk. so if you think there is a way like recovery in disk. no its not. the only way is to save the values or create copy of array. and use it later.

Comment: to the down voters. what is the point of down voting here? dont just downvote because its already downvoted. the question isnt really bad

Comment: The expected response was perhaps related to DataTable class that stores both the initial Row values and the last deletions/modifications.

Answer (score 0):

The key here to me is that it is replaced by 0 not "removed" as the array still has the same length. So, you cannot "retrieve" a value that has been replaced here.